# Data is undefined despite setting in constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to get `queryParams` from a URL and use that to resolve data like this:

```
  data = {
    searchValue: null || undefined
  };
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    route.queryParams.subscribe(params => this.data.searchValue = params.search);
  }

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any> {
    console.log(this.data);
    if (!this.data) {
      throwError(console.error());
  }
```

Despite setting the data in the constructor, it keeps logging it as undefined. I'm not sure why it isn't working, and I would appreciate it if someone could explain in detail what it is I'm doing wrong and how to rectify the issue.

Comment: What is route or url you are hitting ?

Comment: Please show how `resolve` is called.

Comment: @Jeto it's implemented in the class as

`export class ResolverService implements Resolve<any>`

and then use in the routing-module like this

`{
    path: "search-results",
    component: SearchResultsComponent,
    resolve: {
      cres: ResolverService
    }
  },`

Comment: @SunilSingh it's the activatedroute

Comment: @Roj - I talking about the url. What is your url what you see in the browser address bar ?

Comment: @SunilSingh not sure what you mean, but the url is `localhost:4000/search-results?search=tech`

the params are actually logging in console as `{search: "tech"}` so i know getting it works but assigning it to data before resolving seems to be an issue and i'm not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `snapshot` of `ActivatedRoute` instead.

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.data.searchValue = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['search'];
  }
```

Comment: that did the trick. thanks. I used it in the resolver since it already had the ActivatedRouteSnapshot as
`resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any> {
    this.data.searchValue = route.queryParams["search"];`